# How get unique and latest records from ms access query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Table name  - **TotalPendinglist**

```
ID    DAY      VOLNO   REGSNO   FULLCODE
1  21-09-2021  vol 2     165    65-55-0256890
2  21-09-2021  vol 1     223    52-00-0458966
3  05-08-2020  vol 2     165    65-55-0256895
4  30-06-2019  vol 3     88     88-00-5689454
5  30-06-2019  vol 1     365    00-45-6489756
6  01-12-2018  vol 3     88     88-00-5689454
```

Results i need

```
ID    DAY      VOLNO   REGSNO   FULLCODE
1  21-09-2021  vol 2     165    65-55-0256890
2  21-09-2021  vol 1     223    52-00-0458966
3  05-08-2020  vol 2     165    65-55-0256895
4  30-06-2019  vol 3     88     88-00-5689454
```

```
SELECT *
FROM TotalPendingList As M
WHERE Exists(SELECT 1 FROM TotalPendingList WHERE ID=M.ID HAVING M.DAY=Max(Day))
```

above code throwing syntax error

Comment: if VOLNO and REGSNO matches then based on the DAY latest records must be shown

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
SELECT M.*
FROM TotalPendingList As M
WHERE m.ID = (SELECT MIN(m2.ID)
              FROM TotalPendingList as M2
              WHERE M2.DAY = M.Day
             );
```

Your version has several errors, starting with the first `SELECT`.  You have renamed the table to `M`, so your version doesn't work.